# XWIKI Tags integration

Tags: xwiki

we are using our own application for tags management. We would like to integrate it with XWIKI Tag application so it would show our tags.

Is it possible to change a source of tags? To use REST endpoint, our DB, etc.

I checked XWIKI REST API, but it allows page tagging only, there is no way to create a tag (without tagging a page). Our use case is:
1. users create tags in our application
2. user opens XWIKI
3. our tags should be available in auto suggestion when tagging a page.

Any ideas?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to do this via existing plugin/extension.
As all requests to our app. go via proxy, I routed all requests that XWIKI uses to load tags

```
/xwiki/bin/view/Main/?xpage=suggest&classname=XWiki.TagClass&fieldname=tags&input=tag-name
```

to our endpoint and it works.